# Android view visibility after animation

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have 2 simple animation, *fade_in.xml* and *fade_out.xml*. I want login form to be invisible when click login button. And I want it to be visible after when request finished. First part works as I expected, but when request finished, before animation works and login form is invisible.

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

This is fade in and fade out xml is

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="300"
android:fromAlpha="1.0"
android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

My animation methods are

```
void animateStart() {
    Animation animationFadeOut;
    animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out);
    animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            formLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    formLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
}
```

and

```
void animateFinish() {
    Animation animationFadeIn;
    animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
    animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            formLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    formLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
}
```

My form as xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">..</LinearLayout>
```

And screen 
[image: login screen]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the animation listeners and add `setFillAfter(true)` to your animations like this

```
void animateStart() {
    Animation animationFadeOut;
    animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out);
    animationFadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
    formLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
}

void animateFinish() {
    Animation animationFadeIn;
    animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
    animationFadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
    formLayout.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
}
```